# How to change the background color of a Cell in React Bootstrap Table 2 without having to refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap-table

I am using React Bootstrap Table 2 to display a list of data. I have used a custom formatter for a cell which displays the data in a button. I am looking to change the background of this cell based on the value of a state property of the current row. Now, whenever this state property gets changed, the color associated with it is not being updated instantly. It only gets changed when I refresh the entire page.

Is there a way to re-render the table after the property associated with the cell gets changed ? Or is this even the proper approach?

```
 {
    dataField: "status",
    text: "Status",
    sort: true,     
    style: function callback(cell) {
      return { backgroundColor: colorDict[cell] };
    },
    formatter: (status, row) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div class="dropdown text-center">
            <button>
              <i class="material-icons"> more_horiz </i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
              )}
 }
```

Comment: You have a `onTableChange` props on `BootstrapTable` -  See Remote Cell Editing - https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Remote&selectedStory=Remote%20Cell%20Editing&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel